# How can I constantly check and compare values saved in sessionStorage?

Tags: javascript, web-worker, session-storage

I am attempting to use a dedicated web worker (can only be accessed by the script that spawned it) over multiple pages (shared workers are incompatible with Safari and IE prior to 8). Due to this, a new dedicated worker must be created upon each new page load, as the previous worker will no longer be in the scope, so I am using `sessionStorage` to keep track of a variable across pages.

I am trying to set a timestamp from when the first worker is spawned on a login, save this timestamp in `sessionStorage`, then every x minutes after the initial timestamp, send a message to the server to make sure the session is still active.

I am using

```
if (Window.sessionStorage.getItem('last_timestamp') === null {
    //send message to server
    Window.sessionStorage.setItem('last_timestamp', Date.now().getTime());
}
```

to initialize the web worker and first timestamp.

I am unsure about how to constantly compare that timestamp to the current time in order to know precisely when x minutes have passed so that another message can be sent. I am thinking there must be some sort of listener for this, but I have not been able to find anything.

Comment: I never had to do anything like that, but I think your backend should have a built-in that on login, set a _session timeout_ to the client IP, then until the session is gone the user can request pages/services, otherwise redirect to login page.

Comment: @Guedes Okay, but we have another app using a similar setup, so we are sticking with this one. Unfortunately the other app is iOS and is managed differently, which is why I am asking how to do it this way.